# DWG file fonts not displaying correctly

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have recently noticed that when uploading .dwg files to one of our accounts, a number of fonts seem to have been corrupted when viewing the drawings via the Forge Viewer API (see screenshot below). This appears to have become a problem at some point in early August as up until this point, the same drawing would convert and display correctly.

Link showing the drawing not working (uploaded recently) -

[image: Link showing the drawing not working (uploaded recently)]

Link showing the same drawing working (uploaded earlier in the year) -

[image: Link showing the same drawing working (uploaded earlier in the year)]

We have seen this behaviour on several .dwg files uploaded in the last couple of weeks both in this account and another that we operate. No change has been made to the code in our application. Does anybody know what is causing this issue and advise on the best course of action for resolving these problems? I believe the fonts used are Swiss and Swiss Bold.

Comment: Is this a translation issue (in other words, to you have DWGs files that were translated in the past where the fonts show up correctly) or a viewer issue (the same Forge model that was showing fonts correctly in the past is now broken)?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up, this was a regression in the Forge Model Derivative service, specifically in the DWG-to-SVF translator, and a fix is ready to be deployed to production, with the next release planned for end of October 2020.